# ArcGIS for Android sdk: Why does passing a Web App to a PortalItem not work to display a map created online but passing a Web Map does?

Tags: google-maps, mobile, gis, portal

Here is the process I used based on the documentation guide found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/display-a-map.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_4B6428B63FB849378CFB150D862ECA24):

1. Create the portal object by providing the URL string to the portal. In the example below, the public map is accessed from ArcGIS Online (www.arcgis.com):

   ```
   //construct the portal from the URL of the portal
   Portal portal = new Portal("http://www.arcgis.com");
   ```
2. Construct the portal item object by providing the portal and the item ID string for the map:

   ```
    //construct a portal item from the portal and item ID string
    PortalItem mapPortalItem = new PortalItem(portal, 
   "e229d715f7ca4fa980308549fb288165");
   ```
3. Pass the portal item to the map constructor:

   ```
   //construct a map from the portal item
   ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(mapPortalItem);
   ```

However, I realized this would not work (the map would never load and display) whenever I passed an item ID for a Web App, but it did work when I passed in an item ID for a Web Map. Could anyone further explain why PortalItem does not support the display of Web Apps?

Answer (score 0):

Web Apps are not supported because the ArcGISMap is the runtime corollary to a Web Map. A Web App is an HTML/Javascript standalone application and not something that is supported within the runtime SDKs.